# Construct a class from HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I want to write a constructor to set values from a HashMap. Can you please advise what is the best way to do this?

Write now I am using switch statement to call methods based on HashMap key, but I am wondering whether there is any better alternative.

FYI, in the myItems class, I actually have 25 variables to set.

```
public class MainClass{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String[] datakey = br.readLine().split(";"); // getting header, 25 of them
    HashMap<String,String> bookmap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String[] dataarr = line.split(";"); // getting values, 25 of them
    int k = 0;
    for(String d : datakey){
        bookmap.put(d, dataarr[k++]); // Key-Value Pair
    }
    myItems item = new myItems(bookmap); // HOW TO WRITE THIS CONSTRUCTOR?
}


public class myItems {
    String _id="";
    String _name="";
    String _genre="";
    String _language="";
    int _rating=0;
    int _price=0;
    ...........................
    ...//25 OF THEM...
    ...........................


    public myItems(HashMap<String,String> allrec){
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> it = allrec.entrySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            Switch(pairs.getKey()){
                case "id":
                    setid(pairs.getValue());
                    break;
                case "name":
                    setname(pairs.getValue());
                    break;
                Deafult:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    public int getid(){
        return this._id;
    }
    public String getname(){
        return this._name;
    }
    ..............................
    ..............................
    ..............................

    public void setid(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }
    public void setname(String name){
        this._name = name;
    }
    ..............................
    ..............................
    ..............................
}
```

Comment: I think you probably do not even need to use any field at all. Just store the whole thing in the Map itself. See my answer bellow for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just write it strait forward like this:

```
public myItems(HashMap<String,String> allrec){
    setid(allrec.get("id");
    setname(allrec.get("name");
}
```

If you don't want any attribute to be assigned a null value then you should check if the Map returns a null:

```
public myItems(HashMap<String,String> allrec){
    String id = allrec.get(id);
    if(id != null)
            setid(id);
    // ...
}
```

There is actually another solution for your problem. Why bother storing those value in attributes anyway? You can just store them in the Map itself. Your constructor will be something like this:

```
private Map<String, String> mAttributes;
public myItems(HashMap<String, String> allrec) {
       mAttributes = allrec; 
}
```

Note that you should consider making a copy of the whole map instead of storing reference like above. Then write set methods like this:

```
public void setId(String id) {
        mAttributes.put("id", id);
}
```

And your get methods are like this:

```
public String getId() {
        return mAttributes.get("id");
}
```

Comment: By the way, you probably should stick with Java naming convention and name your class MyItems instead of myItems.

Comment: Well, I was iterating because not all the fields might present all the time. May be there will be no 'name' key in some call. Anyway, my main concern is if I have 25-30 set methods, is it possible to optimize the code rather than writing those 30 methods manually?

Comment: If a map does not have a key then Map.get(Object) will return null. You just need to check the return value for null pointer then.

Comment: Technically you can probably use reflect and find method of a class by its name (as in a String). In that case you would probably name your key the same as the method name. But I would advice against that. You will not gain anything in terms of performance. Probably nothing in terms of readability either.

Comment: Whichever way you write it, the agttribute will be null if it's null in the Map, or absent.

Comment: No it is not. He already initialized all attributes to "". So if later it is not reassigned to null it will stay "", which you already know is different from null of course :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Reflection* for that. Imagine that some fields have setters (okay for datastructures, questionable for classes - and what about mutability vs. immutability?), others haven't. Then you could do it like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public void setAll(final Map<String, String> fieldMap) {
    for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fieldMap.entrySet())
        setField(entry);
}
public void setField(final Map.Entry<String, String> entry) {
    setField(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
public void setField(final String name, final String value) {
    final Method fieldSetter = getFieldSetter(name);
    if (fieldSetter != null) {
        fieldSetter.invoke(this, value);
        return;
    }
    final Field field = getField(name);
    if (field != null) {
        field.set(this, value);
        return;
    }
    // Throw some exception
}
public Method getFieldSetter(final String fieldName) {
    return getMethod(getSetterName(fieldName));
}
public static String getSetterName(final String fieldName) {
    return "set" + upperCaseFirst(fieldName);
}
public static String upperCaseFirst(final String s) {
    return Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1);
}
public Method getMethod(final String methodName) {
    final Class<?> clazz = getClass();
    try {
        return clazz.getMethod(methodName, String.class);
    } catch (final NoSuchMethodException ignore) { }
    try {
        return clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, String.class);
    } catch (final NoSuchMethodException ignore) { }
    return null;
}
public Field getField(final String fieldName) {
    final Class<?> clazz = getClass();
    try {
        return clazz.getField(fieldName);
    } catch (final NoSuchFieldException ignore) { }
    try {
        return clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    } catch (final NoSuchFieldException ignore) { }
    return null;
}
```

- There are some exceptions to be handled, you will need to change the source code accordingly.
- AFAIR on Android *Reflection* comes at a performance penalty. You might want to keep an eye on that method's performance.